# How to hide code documentation/comment in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm writing swift in Xcode, reading others' code meanwhile btw. You know that swift has no header file, so the code documentation is just above the code, it's annoying me sometime. So my question is **'Is there some magic way to hide/show the documentation/comment? '**

```
/// I'm talking about hiding this..
///
/// - Parameter name: name
/// - Returns: return
func someMethod(param name:String) -> String {
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Editor -> Code Folding -> Fold Comment Blocks

Shortcut:

- Fold: Shift + Control + Command + Left
- Unfold: Shift + Control + Command + right

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to hide this in all files?

Comment: I do not know how to fold all files